# Magento 2.4 - No route 404 page loading with product page issue

Tags: event-observer, 404-page, redirect-url, magento2.4, noroute

I redirecting 404 not found page to product page using `controller_action_predispatch_cms_noroute_index` event observer.

*Observer:*

```
$request = $observer->getData('request');
$request->initForward();
$params = ['id' => $productId, 'category' => $categoryId];
$request->setParams($params)
    ->setModuleName('catalog')
    ->setControllerName('product')
    ->setActionName('view')
    ->setDispatched(false);
```

Product page loading perfectly but 404 not found page also loaded with it.

Does anyone have an idea?